# ClassPathXmlApplicationContext not parsing spring config correctly

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have an xml config for spring that works in a server environment. I'm trying to initialize the same library of code to reuse in my local console application.  But I keep getting errors from the XML parse.  In Eclipse, I'm getting:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

The XML file is quite large, but starts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:ldap="http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd">
```

The error cites a line number of 24, which is exactly where the beans tag ends above (not the close tag, but the end of the opening tag).  I saw some other posts about this issue, and most didn't apply.  I am trying to get spring to consume these xsd's locally because while Eclipse should be allowed through our firewall, our security team disallows it from the JVM outside eclipse, and getting them to change anything is typically a months long ordeal.

My spring.schemas file is in the META-INF and looks like the below.  Each of those xsd's is in the jar at the specified classpath.

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.3.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.3.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.3.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.3.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.3.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.3.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.3.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd=org/springframework/ldap/config/spring-ldap-2.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/ldap/config/spring-ldap-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap-2.1.xsd=org/springframework/ldap/config/spring-ldap-2.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap-2.2.xsd=org/springframework/ldap/config/spring-ldap-2.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/jms/config/spring-jms.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/jms/config/spring-jms.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/jms/config/spring-jms.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/jms/config/spring-jms.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/jms/config/spring-jms.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/jms/config/spring-jms.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/jms/config/spring-jms.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-4.3.xsd=org/springframework/jms/config/spring-jms.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd=org/springframework/jms/config/spring-jms.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd=my/pfg/umc/cli/spring-repository.xsd
```

Comment: Spring already resolves these locally so you don't need to do anything special for that, looks like you are trying to solve a problem that isn't a problem.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Maybe.  Without my spring.schemas though, I get the same error.  I definitely can open the spring jar and see that they have a spring.schemas and it points to the correct xsd. But when I run, I get that error about not finding the definition of beans.  If I misdiagnosed the issue, how can I proceed?  Is there some extra logging to turn on?

Comment: I doubt there is an issue. Do you get the error while running the application or from the validation in eclipse? That isn’t clear from your question. Another thing is that it isn’t clear how you are packaging/running your application.

Comment: @M.Deinum - I'm running as a console app from inside eclipse.  The validation for the editor doesn't complain.  I am (for the moment) running using 'Debug As...' inside eclipse.  however, I have also packaged it as a runnable jar with the dependencies packaged into the jar.  When I do that, I am getting a different error.  I'm tackling the inside eclipse issue first.

Comment: If you are building a fatjar you have to take special consideration that all files get merged correctly and the fact that that is part of your build is probably the cause of all your issues. Adding your own custom file with xsd locations isn't the solution, if anything it will probably even break proper working of the schema resolution that Spring already does (since about Spring 2.0).

Comment: @M.Deinum - That's a fair point for when running it outside eclipse.  But what about when it's running inside eclipse and hasn't even gotten that far?  Is there a logging I can turn up or something to see where it's going wrong?  I removed my spring.schemas and still get the issue.

Comment: How are you running things inside eclipse, that isn't clear (are you running a main, through maven or ...). Make sure your classpath is correct and includes the proper jar files.

Comment: It's a main.  The classpath contains all the jars.  If it hadn't, i wouldn't even be getting this far.  I exported as a packaged jar instead of extracting the libraries, and it did change the error - to the same one I'm getting in eclipse.  The above error about not finding the 'beans' element in the xsd.  I wish I could elevate the logging and see what file it thinks it's looking at. This all feels like spring isn't finding the xsd for some reason...I just don't know why.

Comment: I found a jar that a co-worker had checked in and was on the classpath that had an incorrect spring.schemas in it.  I removed that and eclipse works.  So you were right.  Spring.schemas was messing it up...just not one I knew about.